# How to check undefind or notexist in knockout loop

Tags: knockout.js

I want to check for element whether it is exist or not in knockout loop because when i am looping this obserable variable it is saying date is undefind , unable to parse.

This is because sometime it is exist in loop or sometime not. So how to check this.

My code is given below but it is not working for me.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: mfFreqList">
        <!-- ko if: date -->
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: { id: 'hid_freqdate_' + freqid, name: 'hid_freqdate_' + freqid  },  value: createDateValue(date)  " />
        <!-- /ko -->        
        <!-- ko if: !date -->
                <input type="hidden" data-bind="attr: { id: 'hid_freqdate_' + freqid, name: 'hid_freqdate_' + freqid  },  value: ''  " />
        <!-- /ko -->    
</div>
```

Comment: Is `date` observable property?

Comment: So not the `data` value is null/undefined but the property itself is not existing at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have properties in a loop which are may or may not exists for a given element then you can use the `$data` binding context property to access them.

In this case Knockout will able to parse your binding because `$data.date` just returns undefined if your property is not exits but does not cause a binding error:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: mfFreqList">
    <!-- ko if: $data.date -->
         Has Date <br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: !$data.date -->
         No Date <br/>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLK4G/).